# Comparison of negative and positive numbers

Tags: delphi, comparison

I have a comparison function that is getting way too complex for what I'm trying to do. I will receive a double that can be positive or negative. I will be storing a global variable that needs to be the smallest value. In terms of comparison, this means it is the smallest positive number, or if the incoming values are negative, the smallest global value could be negative.

My code is turning into a bunch of `if` statements handling if the incoming is positive or negative. Then i need to compare differently if the current global value is positive or negative.

Is there a better way to simply compare two numbers and get the lowest of the two?

Partial example code:

```
if NestObject.RectangularScrap <> 0 then begin
    if NestObject.RectangularScrap > 0 then begin
      //Positive rect scrap
      if(NestObject.RectangularScrap < GBestRect) then begin
        GBestRect := NestObject.RectangularScrap;
      end;
      if(NestObject.RectangularScrap > GWorstRect) then begin
        GWorstRect := NestObject.RectangularScrap;
      end;
    end
    else begin
      //Negative rect scrap
      if GBestRect > 0 then begin
        //Global value is currently positive
        GBestRect := NestObject.RectangularScrap;
      end
      else begin
        //Global value is currently negative, change both values to postive to compare
        if((-1*NestObject.RectangularScrap) < (-1*GBestRect)) then begin
          GBestRect := NestObject.RectangularScrap;
        end;
        if((-1*NestObject.RectangularScrap) > GWorstRect) then begin
          GWorstRect := NestObject.RectangularScrap;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to compare differently? The `<` and `>` operators work on all numbers, not just positive ones. Also, to change the sign of a number, you can simply apply the `-` operator to it; there's no need to *multiply* by –1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried the min function ?

http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Min

Comment: Exactly. See I knew there was a clean way of doing this, I just didn't know the term to search for. Thank you.